# How is the Chinese remainder theorem used in this proof？

Tags: ring-lwe

[image]

Can you explain it in detail ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the chinese remainder theorem to the ring $\prod_{1\leq i\leq r} \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1}$.

This ring is isomorphic to the ring $\times_{1\leq i\leq r} \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1}$. Let call $\phi$ this isomorphism.

Let recall that for all $x \in \prod_{1\leq i\leq r} \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1}$, $x \mod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1}$ is the $i$th coordinate of $\phi(x)$.

Then we compute $t :=\phi^{-1}(t_1 \mod \mathfrak{p}_1^{e_{1}+1}, \dots, t_r \mod \mathfrak{p}_r^{e_{r}+1})$.

Thus $t\in \prod_{1\leq i\leq r} \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1} $ (because $\phi^{-1} : \times_{1\leq i\leq r} \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1} \rightarrow 
\prod_{1\leq i\leq r} \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1}$).

And $t\mod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1}  = \phi^{-1}(t_1 \mod \mathfrak{p}_1^{e_{1}+1}, \dots, t_r \mod \mathfrak{p}_r^{e_{r}+1}) \mod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1}$ $$ = t_i \mod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1} \mod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1} =t_i \mod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_{i}+1}$$

Comment: This is the right idea, but the products of ideals in your answer (starting from the first sentence) are not rings. Instead, you should refer to the *quotient rings* of the ring $R$ modulo those products of ideals.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert You're right, I will modify it.